# How to close/dismiss basic auth prompt window in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, authentication, automated-tests, cypress

I try to test a failing login, so after submitting an empty form, instead of getting "authentication failed" message, I get the auth prompt window which is not a part of the application and which I need to close to get the "authentication failed" message but I don't know how to close this prompt window in Cypress.

[image]

The window gets closed when I manually type esc button. I tried to simulate typing esc button via code:

```
cy.get('body').trigger('keydown', { keyCode: 27});
```

but unsuccessfully.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I have a similar problem to solve

Comment: @Joe Caruso - I found out that this is because of the way our API is implemented and it needs to be refactored in order to get rid of this. I hope at lease this will help you